# How to efficiently rename all files/directories with same name?

Tags: batch-rename

I'm trying to rename a few common files/directories in my music collection. As of now, my music library is organized this way:

```
Music
    Artist
        Album
            Song
            Song
            Song
            .Cover.jpg
            .Scans
```

I would like to change the `.Cover.jpg` and `.Scans` to something different, like:

```
Music
    Artist
        Album
            Song
            Song
            Song
            Cover.jpg
            Artwork
```

However, I can't find a good way to rename all of these files and directories via bash. How could I make this work so that I won't have to rename every single file manually?

Also, in case I sometime in the future change my mind about how I have things named, how can I change the `.Scans` directory to simply `Scans` in every directory under `Music`?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac OS?

Comment: Oh, I see `bash`.

Comment: Probably should have made that more obvious...sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands should work:

```
find -name .Cover.jpg -execdir mv '{}' Cover.jpg ';'
find -name .Scans -execdir mv '{}' Artwork ';'
```

Run them from `Music` dir.

Comment: Absolutely excellent! This did EXACTLY what I needed it to do. I'm still a bit of a CL novice, so it was great to learn about `find` today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the free [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com). It has a good batch rename feature with lots of options. Located under File.